# long.TryParse fails for a hex value that is within Max&Min limits

Tags: c#

This one has me puzzled - Anyone got any ideas as to why this fails

```
long ticks;
if (long.TryParse("8D28457EDF638CG", NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ticks) == false)
    throw Exception <---- this line gets hit
```

This is the converted value and the max and min on my system;

Calc:    39732250662626188

Max:   9223372036854775807

Min:  -9223372036854775808

**EDIT:**
When 8D28457EDF638CG is pasted into Calc it simply remove the 'G'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"8D28457EDF638CG"
```

Is not a valid hex number. "G" is not a digit in hex.

Comment: I get a feeling that some people on SO can see questions while they are typed in :).

Comment: Well spotted! I could not tell why it would fail like that

Comment: @Igor It's just that some questions are typing contests :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There should so be a hat for that: Answered question (with upvotes/accept?) within 30 seconds/one minute of being posted :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sounds like a good idea. Let's see if you get a secret hat within a few minutes. If you do, you know what it's for :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Looking at the list I'm only one vote and accept from snaphat. Their limit was 30 *minutes* though; way too long for SO :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was hoping to figure out the secret behind "it's elementary" hat, but it does not look like that was it :-(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Lol, that would have been a good trigger for it. No luck for me so far though.